# DT fails to load if user changes tabs while Shiny is loading

Tags: r, tabs, shiny, dt

If I change tabs back and forth in navbarpage when Shiny is busy then this will cause problems with loading datatables.

Please see an example below and do this
1) start the app
2) go to the Y-tab immediately when the app starts
3) Back X-tab
4) Wait for the program to finish on X-tab
5) Back to Y-tab. Nothing here!!

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

server = shinyServer(function(input,output) {
  Sys.sleep(5)
  output$X = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(data.frame(x=runif(100),y=runif(100)))
  })
  output$Y = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(data.frame(x=runif(100),y=runif(100)))
  })
})

ui = shinyUI(navbarPage('',
  tabPanel('data X',fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('X'))),
  tabPanel('data Y',fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('Y')))
))

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

I think what happens is that somehow when I access Y-tab some empty datatable is returned because the real one is not yet ready. Then this empty one is never replaced with the real one because Shiny thinks I have already got my data.

This problem also occurs if I go to Y-tab immediately and wait for the app to finish there. In that case the X-tab fails to load properly.

Is this a bug?

How could I overcome this problem?

Comment: Tested that in different browsers. 1) Rstudio viewer -- work well 2) IE- work well 3) chrome -- work well 4) Mozila- bug ... dont know why but really exist -- may be problem in browser version?

Comment: Hmm interesting. For me Rstudio viewer and Opera bug all the time.